# vagrant halt not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, halt

When I try the `vagrant halt` command in my command prompt, it tells me how the 'ssh' executable is not found. So, I followed [these steps](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY) to download putty and generate a key to enter ssh mode. However, when I try the halt command in my putty ssh mode, it says the program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. To run 'vagrant' please ask your administrator to install the package 'vagrant'.

I got the `vagrant up` working just fine, but I want to properly halt it before I shut my computer off.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by using git bash in administrator mode (right click the program, select run as administrator) to halt the vagrant, since it has ssh built in. I had to navigate to the vagrant-local folder inside git bash and execute the `vagrant halt` command.